# Nil class error for array sorting

Tags: ruby

When I tried to shorten an array, I get an error like this:

```
in `sort_by': undefined method `<=>' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
@@secarr=@@secarr.sort_by{ |hotelname, location, cuisine, price| hotelname }
```

Please explain because I am a newbie to ruby.

Comment: Can you show the value of your array ?

Comment: __DON'T CREATE ANSWERS__ just edit your post

Comment: I have merged your unregistered accounts. You can now edit your question to provide additional information, or use the comment facility under individual answers for additional clarification. Please do _not_ post an _answer_ unless it _is_ and answer to the question, Stack Overflow is not a forum.

Comment: All (well, possibly all) of your accounts have been merged together. [Please read this Faq entry about cookie-based accounts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account/44562#44562) Also, StackOverflow isn't a forum; if you have a new question, please ask a new question. If you want to include more information in your question, please [edit it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5661911/edit). If you want to interact with one of the people who has answered, you can leave them a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct in the respect that `hotelname` is being compared among the elements in `@@secarr`. The error message you encountered means that `hotelname` is (sometimes) `nil`, and cannot be compared. Comparison can only be done on classes that include `Enumerable` module. The solution is to, assuming `hotelname` is normally a string, put `to_s` after `hotelname`.

```
@@secarr = @@secarr.sort_by{|hotelname, location, cuisine, price| hotelname.to_s}
```

Comment: To sawa i already mention that i behind the proxies that doesnt allow sesions.that means you wont be able to login.and for second question i am honest with my question not changing my name or anything ,if it is that is done by website.

Comment: Okay. I now understand that you could not edit because you logged in as a different user. But according to Tim in the comment above, you should now be able to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

Expecting your array looks like this.

```
@secarr = ["hotelname", "location", "cuisine", "price"]
```

For ascending

```
@@secarr=@@secarr.compact.sort_by{ |secarr1,secarr2| secarr1 <=> secarr2 }
```

For descending

```
@@secarr=@@secarr.compact.sort_by{ |secarr1,secarr2| secarr2 <=> secarr1 }
```

Comment: -1 It'd produce the exact same error if one of the values being compared is nil.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: I didn't realize that `sort_by` can accept more than one argument in the block for a multidimensional array. Thank's to sawa and Kelvin in comments.

However, if the array is **not** an array of arrays (eg, if it's an array of strings where the fields are separated by `\t`), using `sort_by` with more than one argument will not work; it will raise the error that you mentioned.

If your case is an array of strings where the fields are separated by `\t` (as you put in a deleted answer), and the hotelname is the first field, you must do the following:

```
@@secarr = @@secarr.sort_by { |el| el.split(/\t+/)[0] }
```

Comment: I don't think so. Try `[[5, 6], [1, 2], [3, 4]].sort_by{|x, y|}`.

Comment: As I said, `sort_by` doesn't take more than one argument. I tried your code on IRB and I got `NoMethodError: undefined method '<=>' for nil:NilClass`. Ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: I think sawa meant to write `[[5, 6], [1, 2], [3, 4]].sort_by{|x,y| x }` which works, so you can pass more than 1 arg, at least in the situations where there's an array to "explode".

Comment: @Kelvin and @sawa, thank you! Now I got it! I'll edit my answer.